# Swift 4 Pass variable via Delegate

Tags: swift, delegates, parameter-passing

I have problem to pass **ID** from **ViewController1** to **ViewController3**. I tried to use delegate, but no success... If exist another way to pass **ID** to ViewController3..

VireController1

```
protocol VCFinalDelegate {

func finishPassing()

}

class ViewController1: UIViewController, VCFinalDelegate{

//......
var param: NQTSearchParam!
var uid = String()

private func loadDoctorFromServer(param: NQTSearchParam?){
    progressHub.show(animated: true)
    let request = EVRequestDoctor.shared
    request.delegate = self
    request.findDoctorWithClinicID(clinicID: param?.clinicID, specialtyID: param?.specializationID)

    uid = (param?.clinicID)!
}



func finishPassing(){
    let id = uid
}

//......
}
```

ViewController3

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController{

//......

var delegate: VCFinalDelegate?

private func updateDoctorUI() {

    delegate?.finishPassing()
    print("id: \(delegate?.finishPassing())") //nil

}

//......
}
```

Comment: Where do you move from ViewController1 to ViewController3?

Comment: @Scriptable i wanna display my ID (from VC1) in updateDoctorUI() (VC3), so i tried to use delegate?.finishPassing().  Is my code correct?

Comment: Not really. I dont see any connection between the two view controllers

Comment: @Scriptable i wrote VC1 and VC3 because i have some Controllers in between them, and i display them like self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @Scriptable that's why i have problem to pass data

Comment: So you move from VC1, present VC2, then present VC3 and want to pass data back to VC1 from VC3 at the end?

Comment: You have to store the instance of the passing viewController before you push. That is how you delegate. Also you need to return something to print in that method.

Comment: @Scriptable i have VC1 with my ID, present VC2, then present VC3 where i want to see my ID.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri store id on Struct?

Comment: you dont even need a delegate then. `let vc2 = VIewController2(); vc2.id = id; ` then present vc2

Comment: @Scriptable this way works when you pass from VC1 to VC2 via present. But my case it to pass id from VC1 to VC3

Comment: What is wrong with: `let vc3 = VIewController3(); vc3.id = id;` at some point you need to get from vc1 being on screen to vc3. to do that you need to present view controllers. Pass the ID along as much as you need to when you present each one, or take a look at the coordinator pattern. delegates are normally used to pass information backwards in the flow. when going forwards you can set the values yourself.

Comment: @Scriptable it work... thanks! But i use struct to store data. Why? Because i have lot of field on different ViewControllers where i want to display data like selectedClinicName by ID, address etc. So i think struct is the best choice. Am i right? If you want you can write you answer and i will accept it, it really works.

Comment: I wouldn't create one big 'does everything' struct, model your structs to match your  'real world' objects. so maybe have a User, Doctor, Clinic struct. and pass those around as needed. So if your VC1-3 are about clinics, instead of passing a single ID through the VC's, pass a clinic struct so you have all the data accessible

Comment: @Scriptable true.. i create struct for each entity, now i can manage it easily.

Comment: Sounds good, Thanks for accepting the answer. Good luck with the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to pass data forwards in UIViewControllers you can pass data along by setting properties, so in your case you could...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func nextPagePressed() {
        let vc = ViewController2()
        vc.id = self.id
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

class ViewCotroller2: UIViewController {
    var id: Int = 0

    func nextPagePressed() {
        let vc = ViewController3()
        vc.id = self.id
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

You normally use a delegate for listening to notifications elsewhere, when data is passed *back* to you when something happens.